# querying large number (300k) of csv files stored on S3

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am performing some scraping jobs on EC2, and plan to keep my data on S3 once they are fetched. They will be:

1. 300K individual .csv files
2. each csv file is about 3000 lines and 60 columns. Mostly str data.
3. each csv file is about 3m in size.
4. They are stored on AWS S3.

I will be analyzing these data in details later. I should note that:

1. This is not for production purpose but for a academic research project;
2. We care more about query efficiency than cost;
3. We will probably not constantly querying the data. Probably a few hundred times in the next couple of months;

I imagine I will probably have to use some services on AWS (Athena, or write them to DynamoDB, or RDS?). Of these three services I have no hands-on experience, so I am looking for advice.

Another thought is that: should I save the data in .parquet? I have read about its efficiency over other formats.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Will the anaylzing be with free form queries or a standard list of repeatable queries?

Comment: @Kirk We don't know yet. Would be great to have advice in both scenarios. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without more information from you it is difficult to know what the right solution is, but if the data is already in S3, I'd try and use Athena first. If that does do what you want or costs too much, I'd then look at RDS Aurora MySQL or PostegreSQL or Amazon DocumentDB.

If you are going to make a user facing high performance app where you know the access patterns users will be doing in a repeatable fashion, I'd look at DynamoDB.

First though, you really need to figure out what you want to achieve with this data. That should guide you to the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks, Kirk! I forgot to mention that this is not for product but for academic research. That means we will only query the database a few hundred times in total over the next few months.

Comment: In that case, I'd definitely try Athena first. Also, if the answer helped, please upvote. If you think it is correct mark it as such please.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion. However, I highly recommend that you **test the reporting side before doing all the scraping**, otherwise you might find that the data is being stored in a format that is not compatible with Athena. By testing it up-front, you could make some necessary tweaks (eg putting fields in quotes within the CSV file) rather than having to reprocess all the data after it has been gathered.

Comment: @Kirk Thanks a lot. I will start with Athena. Upvoted. Will mark it accepted if it indeed works out.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you John. I think this is a good point. Will do!